# How to sum row wise and put values in columns using R

Tags: r

the data set is as below -

```
Origin  Destination Days Taken  01-10-2016  02-10-2016  03-10-2016  04-10-2016
   x         a        2    1        3           4           5
   y         b        3    1        6           4           3
   z         c        2    5        1           2           3
   a         b        6    6        8           5           2
   b         y        5    3        3           1           3
   c         a        3    5        3           2           1
```

the result i want is by adding the days taken to the date, the solution is-

```
Origin  Desination  Days Taken  Shipments   Given Date  Reach Date
 x         a          2     1   01-10-2016  03-10-2016
 y         b          3     1   01-10-2016  04-10-2016
 z         c          2     5   01-10-2016  03-10-2016
 a         b          6     6   01-10-2016  07-10-2016
 b         y          5     3   01-10-2016  06-10-2016
 c         a          3     5   01-10-2016  04-10-2016
 x         a          2     3   02-10-2016  04-10-2016
 y         b          3     6   02-10-2016  05-10-2016
 z         c          2     1   02-10-2016  04-10-2016
 a         b          6     8   02-10-2016  08-10-2016
 b         y          5     3   02-10-2016  07-10-2016
 c         a          3     3   02-10-2016  05-10-2016
 x         a          2     4   03-10-2016  05-10-2016
 y         b          3     4   03-10-2016  06-10-2016
 z         c          2     2   03-10-2016  05-10-2016
 a         b          6     5   03-10-2016  09-10-2016
 b         y          5     1   03-10-2016  08-10-2016
 c         a          3     2   03-10-2016  06-10-2016
 x         a          2     5   04-10-2016  06-10-2016
 y         b          3     3   04-10-2016  07-10-2016
 z         c          2     3   04-10-2016  06-10-2016
 a         b          6     2   04-10-2016  10-10-2016
 b         y          5     3   04-10-2016  09-10-2016
 c         a          3     1   04-10-2016  07-10-2016
```

and the output required is -

```
Destination 03-10-2016  04-10-2016  05-10-2016  06-10-2016  07-10-2016  08-10-2016  09-10-2016  10-10-2016
a   1   8   7   7   1           
b       1   6   4   9   8   5   2
c   5   1   2   3               
y               3   3   1   3
```

Please let me know if any other input is required.

Comment: Using the dput() command in R on your data set will make it for people to understand and use your dataset.

Comment: @Tejas In your question there is no data in the columns "04-10-2016" and "Reach Date". Please edit your question. A better way to give example data is the use of the function `dput()`. (see the comment of @Jonno)